# How to show a View such that it obscures the View it is placed on top of?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I want to place a View (A) on top of another View (B). However, when I do so using a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout (such that View A and View B are both set to be in the same position) I can see View B faintly through View A. I want instead for View A to obscure View B totally out of sight. Is this is possible?

> **Note**: ViewSwitcher will not do for my particular need nor will setting the visibility of View B to 'invisible'/'gone' as I need View B to be
>   'visible' and fixed in place whilst View A is sliding/animating in and
>   out of sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by giving View A a background resource, i.e. an opaque drawable or color.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. You can set the `visibility` of the corresponding `View` to either `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE`. Do this in code with [setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) or use xml.

```
<View ... android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately not an option for what I require. Please see the note accompanying my question.

Comment: @AdilHussain It's very unclear what you want to achieve. Thus the view needs to be visible and needs to be invisible at the same time?

Comment: Yes, the View (B) needs to be visible whilst the second view (A) is animating (sliding/fading/whatever) on top of it. I can set the visibility of B to 'gone'/'invisible' when the animation is complete but the problem still remains that I can see B through A whilst A is animating into sight (and their colours become merged).

Comment: so on the start of animating, set B to inivisible/gone?

Comment: Thanks Hades and Michael for the help. The problem with setting B to 'invisible' at the start of the animation is that I want A to look like it is sliding in on top of B (so B must be 'visible' when the animation is running). Conversely, the problem with B being 'visible' is that the user can see it faintly through A whilst A is sliding in on top of it. So I want to know why it is that the View (B in this case) which should be beneath A can still be seen and how to get around this so that A appears 'on top of' B and appears to be obscuring B out of sight...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try declaring (View) B before declaring (View) A?

Can you show me your xml layout, might be able to help.

Comment: Yes. Let's say the xml layout is a FrameLayout containing two ImageViews A & B, where A is defined after B, A & B are both the same size and both are 'visible'. You will find that A is on top of B but that you can see B (faintly) through A. Any way to make it so that you can see A (as is currently the case) but such that B is totally covered (out of sight)?

Comment: See comment on Michael's answer. Apologies to you and @Michael because it seems I explained this question poorly or have asked a poor question.